# ERROR: javah is not working in android studio

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

to create header files i am using javah but its not working for me.

using javah like this.

```
Javah -d ${ D:\finalYearProjectAPP\WorkingCam\app\src\main\jni} -classpath ${ D:\finalYearProjectAPP\WorkingCam\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug } com.example.ahmedarif.workingcam.OpenCvClass
```

and it gives this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a valid class name
: D:\finalYearProjectAPP\WorkingCam\app\src\main\jni}
at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask(JavacTool.java:129)
at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask(JavacTool.java:107)
at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask(JavacTool.java:64)
at com.sun.tools.javah.JavahTask.run(JavahTask.java:503)
at com.sun.tools.javah.JavahTask.run(JavahTask.java:329)
at com.sun.tools.javah.Main.main(Main.java:46)
```

Comment: Did your classes\debug folder contains the class "OpenCvClass".i.e did you build the project before executing javah command

Comment: I build my project before i use that command